# Can you cancel a rabbitmq consumer remotely?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am reading the documentation about `Channel.basicCancel` operation in rabbitmq https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-cancel.html . The docs says that one of possible cancellation case is when consumer sends cancel signal on the same channel on which it is listening.

Is this the only possibility? Can you cancel remote consumer running on different channel/connection/process?

I am trying to send the cancel request from another another process. When I do it ends with an exception `java.io.IOException: Unknown consumerTag` just like such operation was restricted to cancelling local consumers (on own channel or connection).

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that this "Unknown consumerTag" exception is a result of initial validation inside com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicCancel(String):

```
 Consumer originalConsumer = (Consumer)this._consumers.get(consumerTag);
 if (originalConsumer == null) {
   throw new IOException("Unknown consumerTag");
 }
 ...
```

But still there might be some rpc call which does the trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct, you must cancel a consumer from its own channel/connection.

Other options include making your consumers aware of "cancellation messages" that will cause them to stop themselves, or using the API to [close an entire connection](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.6/priv/www/api/index.html), which will close all channels associated with it.